# Lenovo T430 temperature issues? Fan control for Linux?

Tags: linux, laptop, cpu, fan, temperature

> sensors

coretemp-isa-0000

Adapter: ISA adapter

Package id 0:  +63.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

Core 0:        +54.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

Core 1:        +64.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0

Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +61.0°C  (crit = +200.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        3802 RPM

I am having laptop failures, and I think it has to do with thermal control. In particular I am most worried about this part:

temp1:        +61.0°C  (crit = +200.0°C)

critical temp is 200 degrees?!  This can't be right How do I adjust this?!

Comment: This thing isn't your core, so you don't really know what the critical temp is. I just replaced an aging T430 (Ubuntu 14.04) where the fan was permanently blowing at hair-dryer levels of noise and temperature. Yje idling temperatrature was a bit above 50C. Like with all laptops dust/cruft tend to accumulate and reduce the cooling capacities.

Comment: I've cleaned out the fans last week, and Today, re-applied thermal paste. It seems to run at around 55 degrees Celsius at all times.

At home, it reaches beyond 70 degrees easily

Comment: I have seen mine around 85-90 a couple of times.  But 55C looks normal.

Answer (score 0):

After same issues in W7 and Linux side, and exchanging RAM, reapplying thermal paste and etc.
The only 2 things that can be wrong are Motherboard and CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output of another software I use, I do not think your T430 has any temperature issue. The reading *outside* of brackets (i.e. 63, 54, 64 °C) in your case are normal. The numbers *inside* the brackets merely tell you that "your temperature will be considered high only when it raises to 87°C, and it will be considered critical when it reaches 105°C". My experience tells me that, the computer will automatically shut down if it reaches to 105°C.

PS: Currently my T430 can easily go to 80 to 100°C when busy. That is an overheating issue that I need to deal with.